# How to search for a function in a database while using another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Suppose I have some user databases. I want to write a script to tell me which user databases have a function with name **dbo.udf_GetEmployeeRate()**.

That script can be run against any database.

So far I have wrote the script to loop through all the user databases and get the database name in a variable in the loop:

```
declare @v_database_name    varchar(256)
declare @v_function_name_to_search    varchar(25)

select @v_function_name_to_search = 'udf_GetEmployeeRate'

declare c_db cursor read_only local for 
    select name 
    from sys.databases 
    where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'ReportServer', 'ReportServerTempDB') and is_distributor = 0
    order by name
open c_db
while 1 = 1 
begin
    fetch from c_db into @v_database_name
    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        break

    select @v_database_name '@v_database_name'

end
close c_db
deallocate c_db
```

Now the issue is how to find the function name in the database whose name is in the `@v_database_name` variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can use the `sys.all_objects` view, and the prefix of the database: `SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.[sys].[all_objects] WHERE type_desc LIKE '%function%'`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? select * from information_schema.routines where specific_name = ''udf_GetEmployeeRate'' AND routine_type= ''FUNCTION''' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

It will list every database that has the function in it (and return zero row sets for those that don't) but you can modify the query to filter on whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use using dynamic sql

```
use dbname

SELECT routines.routine_name, *
FROM information_schema.routines where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

Answer (score 0):

--Run this script

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FunctionFinder') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #FunctionFinder
    CREATE TABLE #FunctionFinder(ROUTINE_CATALOG NVARCHAR(255), ROUTINE_NAME NVARCHAR(255))
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(500), @fn_Name NVARCHAR(255) = 'udf_GetEmployeeRate'

    SELECT @command = 'USE ? select ROUTINE_CATALOG, ROUTINE_NAME from information_schema.routines where specific_name = ''' + @fn_Name + ''' AND routine_type= ''FUNCTION''' 
    INSERT INTO #FunctionFinder
    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 
    SELECT * FROM #FunctionFinder
```

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 
SELECT * FROM #FunctionFinder

Comment: why in `information_schema.routines` you search by `specific_name` but pick `routine_name` instead in the resultset? can `specific_name` and `routine_name` be different?